# Python Flask app on EC2 AWS, host by apache2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, flask, amazon-ec2, apache2

I'm trying to build a Flask APP, which includes two webpages. The first one allows users to upload an image, after which the server will take the image input and make predictions from CNN and generate some image results. For the first page and from the server end, they both work well. The user upload and image generation are successful. However, the second page won't load the newly generated images. The page shows as bellow:

[The second webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eV4m.png)

Two issues could be possibly related to this:

1. Permission issue? I set the permission of this app folder and subfolders to 777, although the uploaded images and newly generated images are not.  Please see the below image for details of these image permissions.

[ls -la for all images to be shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67VpT.png)

2. Even The pink ones are either uploaded(the first one) or newly generated (the rest two), while green ones are "shutil" copied from another folder. As green images inherit the previous permissions, it should display, but why does it not?

BTW, I also tried the solution [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/142775/write-permissions-on-uploaded-files-linux-apache-php), but it still doesn't work.

Am I on the right track to solve this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Yanyang

Answer (score 0):

Have you inspected to validate that the image path its using as the src is correct? This would be your first step to validate the application is correct.

After that try validating any error logs that may indicate a local file error, this would depend on the web server software you're using.

Comment: Hi, Mokugo. Thanks a lot for answering. How can I check the image path?

Comment: So in your browser you should be able to do a right click and inspect the image on the page. That will show you the HTML and then you can see the path its trying to access

Comment: src is correct.Apache error log shows:
[Thu May 07 07:47:15.833640 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4763:tid 140511079798528] 

[Thu May 07 07:47:15.833690 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4763:tid 140511079798528] Performing object detection:, referer

[Thu May 07 07:47:15.833713 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4763:tid 140511079798528]  , 

[Thu May 07 07:47:28.006847 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 4763:tid 140511071405824] /var/www/html/web/static/images/20030717233822772_original.png,

Comment: I deleted all the client and referer information. sorry for this messy error log.

Comment: So now you can see the file path, can you run a ls -lah over /var/www/html/web/static/images/20030717233822772_original.png?